# How does a chain of Microservices usually handle authorization with limited time-to-live?

Tags: security, jwt, microservices

## The Problem

### Situation

A company has decided to use Microservices. They have three Microservices Bob, Charlie and Dave. User Alice now attempts to do SOMETHING and sends a request to Bob, authenticating herself by handing over a Token (a JWT in our example). Bob checks that Alice is indeed authorized to send the request. After checking that she is authorized in some way he then proceeds to do his thing. To do his thing, he needs to contact Charlie who in turn will have to contact Dave. The whole process runs along asynchronously - as soon as Alice sent her request to Bob and he told her "You're good!" she assumes that the request will be handled accordingly, leading to **eventual consistency** of the whole system.

### Avoiding the Confused Deputy

The [confused deputy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem) tells us that we need to be careful when Bob contacts Charlie and Dave. Bob checked if Alice is allowed to request his services, but he does not necessarily know if she is allowed to request Charlie's and Dave's. A commonly stated solution is that Bob hands over the JWT along with the request so they can check themselves. That's what I found mentioned quite a few times across the web.

### An issue arises

What happens in the case of a failure along the way? For example, what happens if Dave has a bad day and crashes for 4 hours, or if the network is down and he is unable to conctact him? As a good little eventually consistent Microservice we can assume that things will get going again once the outage has been solved, but the JWT will be invalid by then - even though it was perfectly valid when Alice made the request. The system is in an inconsistent state - Charlie can't just repeat the request to Dave (Dave will just refuse the token as it is invalid) and he can't get a new token because he has no way to get one. If he had, he could be impersonating Alice - a no-go in a Zero-Trust-Environment.

## The Question

How do larger structures of Microservices handle this issue normally? It seems to me this *should* be a fairly common issue regarding both Microservices and the concept of Eventual Consistency, but I have been unable to find any literature or blog posts regarding this topic.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly common issue, but it comes primarily from bad design practices.

There shouldn't be a case in which `Bob` checks auth for `Alice` by asking `Charlie` who'll then have to consult `Dave`. This is a leaky context - because it sounds like `Charlie` and `Dave` both do auth, which they shouldn't.

Additionally, there are two things to consider:

- If `Alice` and `Bob` are both internal services, why do you need to verify auth for `Alice` in `Bob` as if `Alice` is going to "lie to you"?
- If `Alice` and `Bob` are both external services (with available public APIs) - then you should run auth check inside `Alice` or `Bob`, whichever catches the public request.

Additionally, all of this chattiness amongst services can be avoided by using a Gateway API - which will run the initial auth, fetch user with his permission flags - then propagate that data to underlying internal services.

---

As for the second issue, Eventual Consistency is a tradeoff we agree to having to achieve high availability. In simpler words:

- if you absolutely need freshest data (auth can be such case) - then don't store replicas of data fetched from AuthService - if it fails, your system fails, that's entirely okay - at least we don't get people doing unauthorized stuff.
- if you don't need freshest data (like user data fetched from authservice to your emailservice) - then storing replicas and eventual consistency tradeoff is completely fine - at least we still have old emails when we're trying to send notifications, and chances are - emails didn't change for a while and are still valid.

Hope this helps - I also write a little bit about similar stuff here: https://obeycode.com/articles/7/microservices-in-simple-terms---introduction

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify a few things:
Bob does not talk to Charlie and Dave to verify whether Alice is authorized. The authorization check completes before Bob starts to do anything else. Charlie and Dave are merely needed for Bob to do his thing (for example, he handles Orders and needs to tell Charlie to get something from the warehouse).
Secondly, Alice is not a service herself, but a user attempting to do something she is authorized to do. The question revolves around how the seperate services can verify she is indeed verified.

Thanks for your link, will check it out.

Comment: I see. In that case 2 solutions are often applied: usage of a Gateway API - which handles all external requests, does the authentication and pushes credentials needed for authorization deeper into the services, or making calls to `AuthService` whenever you need to verify user authorization in service of execution. Is that explanation clear enough?